# Debugging by Thread in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm a beginner in xcode and iphone iOS development while debugging the xcode it shows Thread1,Thread2,Thread3,Thread4 what these threads meant? and how it is useful in debugging can some explain?

Comment: Most of the threads are system threads, the only important one is the "main" thread (Thread 1). All your code runs in this thread unless you actually go and create or use other threads in your code...

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the purposes of debugging your own app, you really only need to worry about Thread1, or at least until such point that you start writing concurrent code (see [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

A thread is basically a particular path of execution of code. Thread1 is the "main thread", the one where your app does its basic operations, all of the user interface code, etc. When you start getting into more sophisticated programming, you might employ concurrency, where you send time consuming operations to a background thread/queue so that it doesn't adversely affect the user experience which is happening on the main thread.

The threads 2, 3, 4, etc. in your question, though, are system generated threads and not ones you generally need to concern yourself with. Only worry about the main thread and, if and when you get into writing concurrent code, those threads to which you are explicitly adding operations.